# ChartJS Axes Callback not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, chartjs

I am building a Scatter graph using ChartJS and I wanted to generate custom X and Y axes.

I have been using the `callback` to try and determine axes values, which seems to work on codepen, but doesn't in Salesforce.

Wondering if anyone else has hit this?

My code is as follows:

JS:

```js
const data = [
  {
    backgroundColor: "#F0F8FF",
    data: [{ y: 1, x: 1 }],
    label: "Person 1",
    pointHoverRadius: 9,
    pointRadius: 9
  },
  {
    backgroundColor: "#00FFFB",
    data: [{ y: 2, x: 2 }],
    label: "Person 2",
    pointHoverRadius: 3,
    pointRadius: 3
  },
  {
    backgroundColor: "#4169E1",
    data: [{ y: 3, x: 3 }],
    label: "Person 3",
    pointHoverRadius: 9,
    pointRadius: 9
  },
  {
    backgroundColor: "#CCCCCC",
    data: [{ y: 4, x: 4 }],
    label: "Person 4",
    pointHoverRadius: 9,
    pointRadius: 9
  },
  {
    backgroundColor: "#FFFF00",
    data: [{ y: 5, x: 2 }],
    label: "Person 5",
    pointHoverRadius: 9,
    pointRadius: 9
  },
  {
    backgroundColor: "#FF0000",
    data: [{ y: 6, x: 4 }],
    label: "Person 6",
    pointHoverRadius: 9,
    pointRadius: 9
  }
];

const yAxisLabels = ["String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 4", "String 5", "String 6"];

const xAxisLabels = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3", "Value 4"];

new Chart("chart", {
  type: "scatter",
  data: {
    datasets: data
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: true
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function (tooltipItem) {
          // This callback does not seems to work
          return data[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          type: "linear",
          ticks: {
            min: 1,
            stepSize: 1,
            display: true,
            // Same with this one
            callback: function (value, index, values) {
              if (Math.round(value) !== value) return null;
              return xAxisLabels[value - 1];
            }
          },
          scaleLabel: { display: true, labelString: "X Axis" }
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          type: "linear",
          scaleLabel: { display: true, labelString: "Y Axis" },
          ticks: {
            min: 1,
            stepSize: 1,
            display: true,
            // And again with this one
            callback: function (value, index, values) {
              if (Math.round(value) !== value) return null;
              return yAxisLabels[value - 1];
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="chart-container">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

If you put the above into a codepen then it renders fine and you can see the axis labeling is correct, however, when I use this in Salesforce it doesn't convert the values from 1, 2, 3, 4, etc... to String 1, String 2, etc...

Comment: Please check if the charts js library version you are using is up to date.

Comment: I am already on the latest version: 2.9.3

Comment: Your code works for me too (as already mentioned by @Barış Arslan). May be there is some other issue in your LWC code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code works on Salesforce when I try it. ApiVersion: 48 ChartJS: 2.9.3

Template:

```
<template>
    <div class="chart slds-var-m-around_medium slds-theme_default" lwc:dom="manual"></div>   
</template>
```

Javascript:

```
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import ChartJS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/chartjs';
import ChartCSS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/chartcss';

import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class ChartTest extends LightningElement {

    chartInitialized = false;
    chart;
    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.chartInitialized) {
            return;
        }
        this.chartInitialized = true;

        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, ChartJS),
            loadStyle(this, ChartCSS)
        ])
            .then(() => {
                window.Chart.platform.disableCSSInjection = true;
                const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                this.template.querySelector('div.chart').appendChild(canvas);
                const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                
                this.initializeChart(ctx);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error loading ChartJS',
                        message: error.message,
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
            });
    }

    initializeChart(ctx) {
        const data = [
            {
              backgroundColor: "#F0F8FF",
              data: [{ y: 1, x: 1 }],
              label: "Person 1",
              pointHoverRadius: 9,
              pointRadius: 9
            },
            {
              backgroundColor: "#00FFFB",
              data: [{ y: 2, x: 2 }],
              label: "Person 2",
              pointHoverRadius: 3,
              pointRadius: 3
            },
            {
              backgroundColor: "#4169E1",
              data: [{ y: 3, x: 3 }],
              label: "Person 3",
              pointHoverRadius: 9,
              pointRadius: 9
            },
            {
              backgroundColor: "#CCCCCC",
              data: [{ y: 4, x: 4 }],
              label: "Person 4",
              pointHoverRadius: 9,
              pointRadius: 9
            },
            {
              backgroundColor: "#FFFF00",
              data: [{ y: 5, x: 2 }],
              label: "Person 5",
              pointHoverRadius: 9,
              pointRadius: 9
            },
            {
              backgroundColor: "#FF0000",
              data: [{ y: 6, x: 4 }],
              label: "Person 6",
              pointHoverRadius: 9,
              pointRadius: 9
            }
          ];
          
          const yAxisLabels = ["String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 4", "String 5", "String 6"];
          
          const xAxisLabels = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3", "Value 4"];

          this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: "scatter",
            data: {
              datasets: data
            },
            options: {
              legend: {
                display: true
              },
              tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                  label: function (tooltipItem) {
                    // This callback does not seems to work
                    return data[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
                  }
                }
              },
              scales: {
                xAxes: [
                  {
                    type: "linear",
                    ticks: {
                      min: 1,
                      stepSize: 1,
                      display: true,
                      // Same with this one
                      callback: function (value, index, values) {
                        if (Math.round(value) !== value) return null;
                        return xAxisLabels[value - 1];
                      }
                    },
                    scaleLabel: { display: true, labelString: "X Axis" }
                  }
                ],
                yAxes: [
                  {
                    type: "linear",
                    scaleLabel: { display: true, labelString: "Y Axis" },
                    ticks: {
                      min: 1,
                      stepSize: 1,
                      display: true,
                      // And again with this one
                      callback: function (value, index, values) {
                        if (Math.round(value) !== value) return null;
                        return yAxisLabels[value - 1];
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          });
    }
}
```

Comment: Eugh.... I realised what I was doing wrong, I have a child LWC `c:ChartJs`, which I am using in multiple places and I think it's the way I am using the functions, it's not recognising them or the vars in them as they are on the parent and being executed on the child D: going to do some testing and update, but thanks for this also!

Comment: Hey Tim I want to do the same thing but I've run into the same issue. Were you able to solve this? My code is outlined here for context: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/391063/chartjs-axes-callbacks-not-able-to-be-passed-from-parent-to-child-component