# ChartJS Axes Callbacks not able to be passed from Parent to Child component

Tags: lightning-web-components, callback, parent-to-child, databinding, chartjs

I am using ChartJS to display numerical values and I am looking to modify the Axes labels to display with commas. I want to do so by having the chart config look like:

```
var xyValues = [
    {x:50, y:7},
    {x:60, y:8},
    {x:70, y:8},
    {x:80, y:9},
    {x:90, y:9},
    {x:100, y:9},
    {x:110, y:10},
    {x:120, y:11},
    {x:130, y:14},
    {x:140, y:14},
    {x:150, y:15}
];

var chartConfig = {
    type: "scatter",
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            pointRadius: 4,
            pointBackgroundColor: "rgb(0,0,255)",
            data: xyValues
        }]
    },

    options: {
        legend: {display: false},
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    min: 40, 
                    max:1000,
                    
                    // What I need to pass to the child
                    callback: function(value) {
                        return value.toLocaleString();
                    },
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{ticks: {min: 6, max:16}}],
        }
    }
};

new window.Chart(ctx, chartConfig);
```

The chart builds correctly with the commas when done in the same component. **My issue is that I wish to create the chart config in a parent component, then pass the config to a child component that will build the chart.**

See the following psuedo code:

```
<!-- Inside Parent component -->

<c-chart chart-config={chartConfig}></c-chart>
```

```
// Inside Chart Child Component

@api chartConfig;

chart;

...

initChart(){
    // Get context etc
    
    this.chart = new window.chart(ctx, this.chartConfig);
}
```

The child component does not run the callback function like the original could. What can I do to allow the child to run chartConfig's callback function?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try running it as eval( 'yourcallback' ) - I think all data that passes through the boundary from parent to child is stringified or otherwise santizied.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for you, but expanding on my comment, you could pass the function as a string like this:

```
callback: "function (value) { return value.toLocaleString();}"
```

Then "hydrate" it in the child:

```
function saferEval(obj) {
  return eval?.(`"use strict";(${obj})`);
}

let localCallback = this.chartConfig.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.callback;

localCallback = this.saferEval(localCallback);
```

(I'm not totally sure if you can use the `localCallback` reference or if you need to full object path).

This will mean you can define the callback in the parent, and have it run in the child.